# AngularJS - add HTML element to dom in directive without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive in which I want to add a svg tag to the current element of the directive. Right now I do this with the help of jQuery

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

    var svgTag = $('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
    $(svgTag).appendTo(iElement[0]);

    ...
    }
```

Yet I don't want the directive to depend on jQuery for this simple task. How would I accomplish the same with AngularJS means (or native JavaScript code).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Why not to try simple (but powerful) `html()` method:

```
iElement.html('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
```

Or `append` as an alternative:

```
iElement.append('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
```

And , of course , more cleaner way:

```
 var svg = angular.element('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
 iElement.append(svg);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/AgGwK/

Comment: thanks that did the trick - new to angularjs ... thanks again

Comment: @dorjeduck you welcome , take a look at jsFiddle link that i attached

Comment: but it is not appending angular controlls

Comment: @MuneemHabib , right it useful for the raw html only. Otherwise you need to use `$compile` : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 16):

In angularJS, you can use angular.element which is the lite version of jQuery. You can do pretty much everything with it, so you don't need to include jQuery.

So basically, you can rewrite your code to something like this:

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  var svgTag = angular.element('<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>');
  angular.element(svgTag).appendTo(iElement[0]);
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot nXqd, that does it indeed. (I already accepted Cherniv's answer...) Thanks for pointing this possibility out to me, will be helpful for more complicated stuff I am sure ...

Comment: btw, if you need to squeeze every ms, you should use the native function from html, but hopefully it does work cross browser. Btw, you can unaccept it :P [ just kidding ]

Comment: angular.element does not have .appendTo https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: ..but it does have append so just switch parent/child situation

Comment: For **prepending** `angular.element(svgTag).prependTo(iElement[0]);`.  Thanks @nXqd

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like this

```
var el = document.createElement("svg");
el.style.width="600px";
el.style.height="100px";
....
iElement[0].appendChild(el)
```

Comment: Thanks pavel for the answer. I tried this yet all I get is "<svg></svg>" in the dom without the width,height attributes (in google chrome)

Comment: you need Element.style.width

Comment: Thanks Kayo. I just tried  el.style.width=600; but still no success, guess I misunderstood your answer

Comment: el.style.width = '600px'

Answer (score 2):

If your destination element is empty and will only contain the `<svg>` tag you could consider using `ng-bind-html` as follow :

Declare your HTML tag in the directive scope variable

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

    scope.svgTag = '<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg"></svg>';

    ...
}
```

Then, in your directive template, just add the proper attribute at the exact place you want to append the svg tag :

```
<!-- start of directive template code -->
...
<!-- end of directive template code -->
<div ng-bind-html="svgTag"></div>
```

**Don't forget to include** `ngSanitize` to allow `ng-bind-html` to automatically parse the HTML string to trusted HTML and avoid insecure code injection warnings.

[See official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) for more details.