# How can my template include an element whose type is determined by an expression in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

It's 2022 and sadly I'm learning AngularJS (already past end of life!)

I need need to use what might be called a dynamic element/component. Pseudocode example:

In controller:

```
   this.theElementName = 'b';
```

In the template:

```
   <{{$ctrl.theElementName}}>this is some text</{{$ctrl.theElementName}}>
```

I would want this to create `<b>this is some text</b>`.

The reason is that I want to generate an array of different directives to render, and I **don't** want code like:

```
<b ng-if="$ctrl.theElementName === 'b'">this is some text</b>
<div ng-if="$ctrl.theElementName === 'div'">this is some text</div>
<directive-abc ng-if="$ctrl.theElementName === 'directive-abc'">this is some text</directive-abc>
...
```

In Svelte, it's

```
<svelte:element this={theElementName} />
```

In Vue it's

```
<div :is="theElementName" />
```

### EDIT: in response to the reluctant 'that person', clarifying the use-case

Consider a user-configurable UI. The result of the configuration might be an array list of components desired. I would then need to loop and output those different components in my template. Of course the components would need a standard interface for properties passesd in, events emitted etc. but that can all be designed for.

My code could do a big switch statement, but that requires prior knowledge of every possible component that might be used now or in the future. By doing it the way I intend to, however, a future person could add a component without needing to touch this code.

Comment: I'm sorry to be "that person", but why? This sounds like you're fighting the framework. You can mess with the compile service if you want to, but I'm not kidding when I say that is a can of worms you should avoid opening and even more-so avoid handing to one of your colleagues.

Comment: To offer something a little more substantive to your question, have you looked into having the parent element use a directive to manipulate these elements for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488803/angularjs-add-html-element-to-dom-in-directive-without-jquery

Comment: Thanks for your input, I've added detail to the question. I think the fact that modern frameworks provide a simple way to do this makes the case that if what I intend to do is "fighting the framework" it's only because the framework makes it a fight.

Answer (score 1):

You can write directive `my-directive` to use:

```
<div my-directive="$ctrl.theElementName">...
```

to generate:

```
<div><component-a>...
<div><component-b>...
<div><component-c>...
```

All directive should do is to generate html string and compile it:

```
element.append($compile('<' + scope.myDirective + '>...')(scope))
```

(also remember to update content in onChanges if you want to support it)

Directive may also copy certain/all attributes from original element etc.

P.S. you should be cautious e.g. if component name comes from database that may allow injections.

Answer (score 0):

Not a brilliant solution, but documenting what is more of a workaround.

`ng-include` can be used to source another template file. That file can contain the component you need to include.

```
<ng-include src="'/path/to/' + theElementName + '.html'"></ng-include>
```